# Limit of f(x) knowing limit of f(x)/x

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Given that:
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=0$$
How can I prove that:
$$\lim_{x\to0} f(x)=0$$
?

Would the L'Hospital's Rule be applicable?

Comment: Given that the first limit _exists_, I think that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$ must hold.

Comment: thing which is given , we can write limit of [f(x)-0]/[x-0]=0, hence given thing is derivative of f(x) at 0 i.e. f'(0)=0

Comment: L'Hospital's rule applies to calculating derivatives, but you have no assumptions about $f(x)$ being differentiable..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Hint :

$f(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}{x}$ and product rule.

Comment: Clearly the best method in this case.

Comment: Product rule is a rule of derivative calculations, but the problem assumes nothing about differentiability....

Comment: @CiaPan By "product rule" I mean [product rule for limits](http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Proofs_of_Some_Basic_Limit_Rules)

Answer (score 4):

If by contradiction $f(x)\to a\neq0,\;\infty$, your limit $\lim f(x)/x$ would be $\infty$. How can you obtain a contradiction if $\lim f(x)$ doesn't exist?

Comment: ....How indeed?

Comment: It actually suffices to consider what happens if the limit doesn't tend to 0. You can construct a sequence $\{x_n\}$ tending to $0$ such that $f(x_n)<\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, if $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)/x = 0$ then for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist small enough $x$ such that

$$-\epsilon<f(x)/x<\epsilon$$
therefore, since $x\ne0$
$$-\epsilon\cdot x<f(x)<\epsilon\cdot x$$ and when $x\in (0, 1)\cup(-1, 0)$ we get 
$$-\epsilon<f(x)<\epsilon$$
which implies that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$

Answer (score 3):

Because the $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=0$, this means that $f(x)$ tends to $0$ faster than $x$, or that $|f(x)|\le x$.

Therefore:

$$0\le|f(x)|\le x $$

Using the squeeze theorem, and because $\lim_{x\to0} x=0$, $\lim_{x\to0} f(x){x}=0$.

Comment: Although there may exist a point of view in which your first sentence is right, I believe that it is not at all a rigorous thing to say (i.e. if I get an homework with those words, I won't never give full mark). This said, in order to deduce $|f(x)<x$ there must be some work required (perhaps using the formal definition of limit applied to the hypothesis).

Comment: To expand on rafforaffo's comments: there is nothing wrong with saying $|f(x)| < x$ for $x$ *sufficiently close to zero* (well, if you justify the statement formally, at any rate), but it may not hold in general.  For example, let $f(x) = x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

By the definition of a limit, f (x) / x < eps for every eps if x is small enough. Take eps = 1, so f (x) / x < 1 if x < eps1, or f (x) < x if x < eps1. Take the definition of the limit again; f (x) < eps if you take x < min (eps, eps1).

Obviously you don't need that the limit of f (x) / x is 0. If the limit is c, then f (x) / x < c+1 for small x, so f (x) < x * (c + 1) for small x, and f (x) < eps if x < eps / (c + 1).

Obviously you'll have to add a few absolute values in the argument.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a fancy proof.  It is a grinding one from the epsilon-delta definition of limit suitable for an introductory calculus class.

The core of the idea is that if $f(x)$ is bounded away from $0$ as $x$ goes to zero, then $f(x)/x$ is also bounded away from zero, as for small $x$, dividing by $x$ makes things further from zero.

And things bounded away from zero don't have a limit of zero.

---

Suppose the limit as $x$ goes to zero of $f(x)$ is $a$, and $a > 0$.

Let $\epsilon = a/2$.  Then there is a $\delta$ such that for all $0 < x < \delta$, $a/2 < f(x) < 3a/3$.

Let $\delta_0$ be the minimum of $1/2$ and $\delta$.

**(statement 1)**: Then for $0 < x < \delta_0$, $f(x)/x \geq f(x)*2 \geq 2a/2 = a$

If the limit of $f(x)/x$ as $x$ goes to zero is $0$, then let $\epsilon = a/2$.

**(statement 2)**: Then there exists a $\delta_1 > 0$ such that for all $0 < x < \delta_1$, $-a/2 < f(x)/x < a/2$

Let $\delta_2$ be the least of $\delta_0$ and $\delta_1$.

For $x < \delta_2 <= \delta_1$, $f(x)/x < a/2$ by **(2)**.

For $x < \delta_2 <= \delta_1$, $f(x)/x \geq a$ by **(1)**.

Thus $a/2 > a$ or $1/2 > 1$, a contradiction.

A similar result holds of $a < 0$.  Spotting the places where I implicitly assumed $a$ was positive may be interesting.